# Outer join to check existence each records of two pandas dataframes like SQL

Tags: python, pandas, merge, outer-join

I have to tables looks like following:

**Table T1**

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 2 |

**Table T2**

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 1 |
| D | 2 |

in SQL I will do following query to check the existence of each record

```
select 
COALESCE(T1.ColumnA,T2.ColumnA) as ColumnA
,T1.ColumnB as ExistT1
,T2.ColumnB as ExistT2
from T1
full join T2 on 
   T1.ColumnA=T2.ColumnA
   and T1.ColumnB=T2.ColumnB
where 
 (T1.ColumnA is null or T2.ColumnA is null)
```

I have tried many way in Pandas like concate, join, merge, etc, but it seems that the two merge keys would be combined into one.
I think the problem is that I want to check is not 'data columns' but 'key columns'.
Is there any good idea to do this in Python? Thanks!

| ColumnA | ExistT1 | ExistT2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | null |
| A | null | 4 |
| C | 2 | null |
| D | null | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.merge` has an `indicator` parameter that could be helpful here:

```py
(t1
.merge(t2, how = 'outer', indicator=True)
.loc[lambda df: df._merge!="both"]
.assign(ExistT1 = lambda df: df.ColumnB.where(df._merge.eq('left_only')), 
        ExistT2 = lambda df: df.ColumnB.where(df._merge.eq('right_only')) )
.drop(columns=['ColumnB', '_merge'])
)

  ColumnA  ExistT1  ExistT2
1       A      3.0      NaN
3       C      2.0      NaN
4       A      NaN      4.0
5       D      NaN      2.0
```

Comment: Minor suggestions: No need for `np.where`, use `df['ColumnB'].where`. Also, If you `pop` the columns in your last `assign` you can remove the `drop`. On the other hand, this is less explicit.

Comment: `pop` in the last assign; show me this magic!

Comment: `ExistT2 = lambda df: df.pop('ColumnB').where(df.pop('_merge').eq('right_only'))`, but it's definitely less explicit ;)

Comment: ahhhh, I see what you mean; that's a good one right there

Answer (score 0):

**First**

- merge 2 dataframes

following code:

```
(df1.assign(ExistT1=df1['ColumnB'])
 .merge(df2.assign(ExistT2=df2['ColumnB']), how='outer'))
```

output:

```
    ColumnA ColumnB ExistT1 ExistT2
0   A       1       1.00    1.00
1   A       3       3.00    NaN
2   B       1       1.00    1.00
3   C       2       2.00    NaN
4   A       4       NaN     4.00
5   D       2       NaN     2.00
```

**Second**

- drop `ColumnB` and same value rows (like row 0 and row2)

include full code:

```
 (df1.assign(ExistT1=df1['ColumnB'])
     .merge(df2.assign(ExistT2=df2['ColumnB']), how='outer')
     .drop('ColumnB', axis=1)
     .loc[lambda x: x.isnull().any(axis=1)])
```

output:

```
    ColumnA ExistT1 ExistT2
1   A       3.00    NaN
3   C       2.00    NaN
4   A       NaN     4.00
5   D       NaN     2.00
```

**Final**

`sort_values` and `reset_index` (full code)

```
(df1.assign(ExistT1=df1['ColumnB'])
 .merge(df2.assign(ExistT2=df2['ColumnB']), how='outer')
 .drop('ColumnB', axis=1)
 .loc[lambda x: x.isnull().any(axis=1)]
 .sort_values(['ColumnA']).reset_index(drop=True))
```

result:

```
    ColumnA ExistT1 ExistT2
0   A       3.00    NaN
1   A       NaN     4.00
2   C       2.00    NaN
3   D       NaN     2.00
```